# How apply Leibinz Rule in $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Big\{ \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-\tau))}^{x+c(t-\tau)} f(s, \tau)ds \, d\tau \Big\}$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Big\{ \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-\tau))}^{x+c(t-\tau)} f(s, \tau)ds \, d\tau \Big\}$$

I have seen examples as a start point, but i can't find one like it. Any tip will be apreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon taking the first partial derivative we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \int_0^t \int_{x-c(t-\tau))}^{x+c(t-\tau)} f(s, \tau)ds \, d\tau \\\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{0}^{t} c\left(f(x+c(t-\tau),\tau)+f(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)\right)\,d\tau\
\end{align}$$

since $\int_x^x f(s, \tau)\,ds=0$.  Then, taking another partial derivative we find

$$\begin{align}
I&=2cf(x,t)+\int_{0}^{t} c^2\left(f_1(x+c(t-\tau),\tau)-f_1(x-c(t-\tau),\tau)\right)\,d\tau\
\end{align}$$

where $f_1$ designates the partial derivative with respect to the first variable.

Comment: Hi, Dr.MV. I've done the first derivative, but i don't understand why you say $$\int_x^x f(s, \tau)\,ds=0$$

Comment: When applying Leibniz's Rule, we have to consider both the integration limits in the context of the FOC along with bringing the derivative inside the integral.  When evaluating $x\pm c(t-\tau)$ at $\tau =t$, we have that the upper and lower limits are $x$.